# Audio not playing in background using AVAudioPlayer iOS 9

Tags: avfoundation, avaudioplayer, ios9.3

Audio is not playing in background using AVAudioPlayer iOS 9 while it is playing in foreground state.

I have already set **Required background modes** '**App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay**' in Info.plist

I have also checked **Audio, Background fetch** in **Capabilities**

Used code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *ringtonePlayer;


    NSString *ringtonePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"incoming" ofType:@"wav"];
    if ([ringtonePath length] <= 0) {
        NSLog(@"Can't find incoming sound file");
        return;
    }

    self.ringtonePlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ringtonePath] error:nil];
    self.ringtonePlayer.delegate = self;
    self.ringtonePlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                                                error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to reroute audio: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
    }

    self.ringtonePlayer.volume = 1.0f;
    [self.ringtonePlayer play];
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following codes to paly in the background,and don't need to modify the info.plist file.

```
func setupPlayBackground(){

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        } catch let error {

            print(error.localizedDescription)

        }

    }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! I was missing this and nothing worked but this fixed it!